# SLIM PHP Routing Type

Tags: php, api, rest, slim

I'm working on updating my Slim API and wanted to add the ability to define the type of response for a route within the routes url. Similar to how Reddit or Rails does it where you can add a .html,.json, or .xml to a route and have that route return the proper formatted data. Below is a Reddit example of one route being able to return a json,xml, or html response by changing the ending to whatever response type.

http://www.reddit.com/r/ObjectiveC.json

Is this something I will have to do manually with middleware parsing every route or does Slim have this built in? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for isn't natively available, but you might want to look at the [ContentTypes Middleware](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Middleware/blob/master/src/Slim/Middleware/ContentTypes.php) in the Slim-Middleware repo.  I think that'll get you close to where you need to go, although the type is detected via the content type header via [`\Slim\Http\Request::getMediaType`](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/Slim/Http/Request.php#L413).